# images not displaying after save into cache

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

I am using `SDWebImage` framework to cache the images in my application.

I have stored all urls in Database. The url is coming correctly, but only the placeholder image is displaying.

```
[cell.productCategoryImg sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgStr]
                           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"zamor.png"]
                                    options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

Comment: show us the code you are using to display image...

Comment: [cell.productCategoryImg sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgStr] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"zamor.png"] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];

Comment: in this imgStr am getting the url string. eventhough it displaying the placeholder image..

Comment: check what is the size of the image... if its big it will take time to load...

Comment: I am getting that image while am in online. but offline am not getting the image.

Comment: yes, offline you will not get it... ]

Comment: why? am storing that url in database only..

Comment: in coredata am saving that urls.

Comment: As you are setting options SDWebImageRefreshCached you each time sdwebimage will try to fetch updated image from server.

Comment: then what should i do?

Comment: please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: remove options:SDWebImageRefreshCached and try again...

Comment: @Iphonenew I am facing same issue. Did you get any solution? please let me know